# Firestore Functions: handle map value

Tags: node.js, hashmap, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

First of all I have to say that I have and intermediate experience on Java and very very basical with JS.

I'm trying to remove expired tokens from my database, for achieve that I did:

```
function sendNotificationToUser(payload, userSnapshot) {
    const userId = userSnapshot.id;
    const user = userSnapshot.data();
    let tokenMap = user.tokens;
    const tokens = Object.keys(tokenMap);

    const options = {priority: "high"};
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options).then(response => {
        // For each message check if there was an error.
        response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
            const error = result.error;
            if (error) {
                // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
                if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                    tokenMap.delete(tokens[index]);
                }
            } else{
                console.log("Sent to user: ", user.name, " " ,user.surname, " notification: ", payload, " tokens: ", tokens[index]);
            }
        });

        usersRef.doc(userId).update({
            tokens: tokenMap
        });
    });
}
```

No problem to get the keys of the tokenMap, but **looks like I can't remove entries with .delete()**, since I got that in my Log:

> TypeError: tokenMap.delete is not a function
>       at response.results.forEach (/user_code/index.js:127:36)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at admin.messaging.sendToDevice.then.response (/user_code/index.js:122:26)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

**What is the reason??**

Comment: Can you show the code that's trying to call .remove?  If you're trying to remove from `results`, that won't remove it from the database anyway. It would just remove it from your result set.

Comment: sorry, the call is tokenMap.delete(), I miswrited :D

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

```
delete tokensObj[tokensArray[index]];
```

**Full code:**

```
function sendNotificationToUser(payload, userSnapshot) {
const user = userSnapshot.data();
let tokensObj = user.tokens;
const tokensArray = Object.keys(tokensObj);

let toUpdate = false;

const options = {priority: "high"};
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokensArray, payload, options).then(response => {
    // For each message check if there was an error.
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                toUpdate = true;
                delete tokensObj[tokensArray[index]];
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Sent to user: ", user.name, " ", user.surname, " notification: ", payload, " token: ", tokensArray[index]);
        }
    });

    if (toUpdate === true) {
        userSnapshot.ref.update({ tokens: tokensObj }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
});
```

}